# Unable autofilling id field when add form is called

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

Well, I'm unable to autofill the id field when I click the add button. The id field is a dropdown field with various choices built automatically by grocery crud as 1_n relation result. I have been using hidden field and if statement in order to autofill when i'm going to add, but the field appears empty and i can't save the form. What am I doing wrong?

**Empty field**
[image: id empty field]

**The controller**

```
public function entregas_lista($idCarga, $op = '') {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        if ($this->Entregas_Model->get_rows($idCarga)) {
            $crud->unset_add();
        }

        $crud->set_language("spanish");
        $crud->set_theme('flexigrid');

        $crud->set_table('entregas');           

        $crud->display_as('idCitas', 'Cita');
        $crud->display_as('idAcciones', 'Acción');
        $crud->display_as('idEstadoSolicitud', 'Estado Solicitud')
                ->display_as('horaCita', 'Hora Cita')
                ->display_as('numeroEntrega', 'Nº Entrega')
                ->display_as('Origen', 'Orígen')
                ->display_as('cargaPrevista', 'Carga Prevista')
                ->display_as('entregaPrevista', 'Entrega Prevista');


        $crud->where('entregas.idCitas =', $idCarga);    

        $crud->display_as('idCarga', 'Nº Entrega');

        $crud->set_relation('idCitas', 'citas', 'cita');

        $crud->set_relation('idAcciones', 'acciones', 'nombreAccion');

        $crud->set_relation('idEstadoSolicitud', 'estadosolicitudes', 'nombreEstado');

        $crud->add_fields('idCitas', 'idAcciones', 'idEstadoSolicitud', 'fechaCita', 'horaCita', 'numeroEntrega', 'cliente', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'cargaPrevista', 'entregaPrevista');
        $crud->edit_fields('idAcciones', 'idEstadoSolicitud', 'fechaCita', 'horaCita', 'numeroEntrega', 'cliente', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'cargaPrevista', 'entregaPrevista');

        if ($op == 'add') {


            $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCarga);
        }


        $output = $crud->render();


        $this->_example_output($output);


     }
```

**I have tried this too:**

```
 if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
            $crud->change_field_type('cita', 'hidden', $idCarga);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, when set_relation two tables the id can't be set so, we must do this with normal field and it works with hidden field:

I hope this will help more people with same problem.

```
if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
            $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCarga);
        }
```